Scrapping hidden tr and td values from table
This is one row from the table. I need to get the values for data-league, data-home, data-away, data-time, data-date, certainty, odds, and the 69% for every row in the table. The 69% will always be a percentage but the number will vary from 1-100%. Several of the elements in this table are hidden and are only shown in the source code.
<tr class="match" data-league="Premier League" data-home="Arsenal FC" data-away="Ipswich Town" data-time="20:15" data-date="Fri. 27 Dec." data-timelocal="8">
                    <td class="date">Thu Dec 26</td>
                    <td class="team" data-match-index="5"><div class="container" bis_skin_checked="1"><div class="ali-left" bis_skin_checked="1"><span class="arrow"></span></div><div class="home-team" bis_skin_checked="1"><div class="arrow-above-home" bis_skin_checked="1"><u><strong>Arsenal FC</strong></u></div></div><div class="home-team-logo" bis_skin_checked="1"><img src="./new_logos/fc-arsenal_11.webp" alt="Arsenal FC logo" loading="lazy" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 1px; border-radius:8px;"></div><div class="score" bis_skin_checked="1"><strong>1:0</strong></div><div class="away-team-logo" bis_skin_checked="1"><img src="./new_logos/ipswich-town_677.webp" alt="Ipswich Town logo" loading="lazy" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 1px; border-radius:8px;"></div><div class="away-team" bis_skin_checked="1">Ipswich Town</div></div><div class="collapsible-container" bis_skin_checked="1"><div class="collapsible-content" bis_skin_checked="1"><div bis_skin_checked="1"></div><div bis_skin_checked="1"></div><div class="li-collaps" bis_skin_checked="1"><strong>Form: </strong><strong><span style="color: green;">W</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #B8860B;">D</span></strong><strong><span style="color: green;">W</span></strong><strong><span style="color: green;">W</span></strong></div><div class="li-collaps><ul class=" ul-colaps"="" bis_skin_checked="1"><li class="li-collaps"> Tomiyasu</li><li class="li-collaps"> White</li><li class="li-collaps"> Zinchenko</li><li class="li-collaps"> Saka</li></div></div><div bis_skin_checked="1"></div><div class="collapsible-content" bis_skin_checked="1"><div class="li-collaps" bis_skin_checked="1"><strong>Form: </strong><strong><span style="color: red;">L</span></strong><strong><span style="color: red;">L</span></strong><strong><span style="color: green;">W</span></strong><strong><span style="color: red;">L</span></strong></div><div class="li-collaps><ul class=" ul-colaps"="" bis_skin_checked="1"><li class="li-collaps"> Tuanzebe</li><li class="li-collaps"> Ogbene</li></div></div><div bis_skin_checked="1"></div></div></td>
                    <td class="certainty">0.98 vs -2.43</td>
                    <td class="odds">1.13</td>
<!--                    <td style="background-color: {'r': 61, 'g': 255, 'b': 0};">69%</td>-->
                    <td style="color: #121212; background-color: rgb(
                        48.800000000000004,
                        204.0,
                        0.0
                    );">
                        69%
                    </td>
                    <td class="correct"><span class="green">✓</span></td>
                    <td class="gp">⚽⚽<br>2.2</td>
<!--                    <td style="background-color: ;"></td>-->
                    <td class="warnings">
            <span class="tooltip"> 
                <span class="tooltiptext">
                
                    Home team has considerable injuries
                
                </span>
            </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="warnings">
            <span class="tooltip"> 
                <span class="tooltiptext">
                    
                        Away team has a dip in form recently
                    
                </span>
            </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

When I try to scrape the table, I only get the visible td values. I can't get the hidden tr and td values.
Code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://ai-goalie.com/28.12.2024.html')
table = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'myTable')
rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')

# Iterate over each row
for row in rows:
    # Find all the cells in the row
    cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')

    # Extract text from each cell
    row_data = [cell.text for cell in cells]
    print(row_data)

driver.quit()

Result:
['Sat Dec 28', 'Arsenal FC\n1:0\nIpswich Town', '', '1.13', '69%', '✓', '⚽⚽\n2.2', '', '']

This result is missing the data-league, data-time, data-date, and certainty. The desired output is the values for
[data-league, data-home, data-away, data-time, data-date, certainty, odds, probability (69%)]


"using a common method" -- do you expect us to guess?  Show us exactly how you retrieved those values.

Can you give some examples of html elements that your code does not find?

it is unclear what you mean by hidden values - do you mean how to scrape the attribute elements of the tr tag? Could you give an example of the output that you are looking to generate?

This question is similar to: Get content of HTML comment tag with Selenium. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I couldn't figure out how to use selenium, so I just used regex on the page's source code. This gets everything I want asides from the odds.
from urllib import request
import re
import pandas as pd

response = request.urlopen("https://ai-goalie.com/index.html")
# set the correct charset below
page_source = response.read().decode('utf-8')

data_league = re.findall("(?<=data-league=\")[^\"]*", page_source)
data_home = re.findall("(?<=data-home=\")[^\"]*", page_source)
data_away = re.findall("(?<=data-away=\")[^\"]*", page_source)
data_time = re.findall("(?<=data-time=\")[^\"]*", page_source)
data_date = re.findall("(?<=data-date=\")[^\"]*", page_source)
certainty = re.findall("(?<=\"certainty\">)[^<]*", page_source)
probability = re.findall("\d+%(?=\n)", page_source)

df = pd.DataFrame({'league': data_league, 'home_team': data_home, 'away_team': data_away, 'time': data_time, 'date': data_date, 'certainty': certainty, 'probability': probability})


You are trying to get the visible texts of the rows in your selenium code. It will not give you all the data as some are in the rows' attribute. Also cell.text will not work when the element is not visible and many rows are not visible on the page. To get those text you need to use cell.get_attribute('innerText').
The list of data you seek can be easily extracted by getting the attribute values instead of the visible texts.
Try the following code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run in headless mode (no GUI)
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1980,1080")  # Set window size
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options)
driver.get('https://ai-goalie.com/28.12.2024.html')
rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#myTable tr.match')

# Iterate over each row
for row in rows:
    #get the data from attributes
    data_league = row.get_attribute('data-league')
    data_home = row.get_attribute('data-home')
    data_away = row.get_attribute('data-away')
    data_time = row.get_attribute('data-time')
    data_date = row.get_attribute('data-date')

    #get the data from td elements
    certainty = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.certainty').get_attribute('innerText')
    odds = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.odds').get_attribute('innerText')
    probability = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td[style]').get_attribute('innerText').strip()

    print(f'{data_league} {data_home} {data_away} {data_time} {data_date} {certainty} {odds} {probability}')

driver.quit()

it will give you the expected result like the following:
Scottish Premiership Celtic FC St. Johnstone FC 15:00 Sun. 29 Dec. 1.7 vs -2.77 1.1 77%
Cambodian Premier League Phnom Penh Crown Kirivong Sok Sen Chey FC 11:00 Sat. 28 Dec. 1.43 vs -2.83 1.39 74%
Liga Portugal FC Porto Boavista FC 20:30 Sat. 28 Dec. 1.41 vs -2.68 1.11 74%
Serie B US Sassuolo Cosenza Calcio 14:00 Sun. 29 Dec. 1.35 vs -2.47 1.36 73%
Premier League Arsenal FC Ipswich Town 20:15 Fri. 27 Dec. 1.13 vs -2.37 1.13 71%

